# How to set the date to be 3 minutes ahead

Tags: javascript, date, timer

I need a timer for my program so my idea was to use the Date() and a future date to make the difference between them a timer,but i have been having problems with Date() functions,where the `future` returns null

```
var date = new Date();
var future = date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes + 3);

console.log(future); //prints NAN

var distance = future - date;
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

Comment: `getMinutes()` is a function ... you forgot the `()` to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getMinutes` as a method call and  add 3 to that.

```
let future = new Date((date = new Date()).setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 3));
```

```js
let future = new Date((date = new Date()).setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 3));
console.log(future.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getMinutes` as a method call, not a property, and add 3 to that.

```
let future = new Date((date = new Date()).setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 3));
```

```js
let future = new Date((date = new Date()).setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 3));
console.log(future);
```